# Adding and Editing tabs on Organic Tabs

Tags: jquery, tabs

I'm currently trying to create a schedule using Organic Tabs (http://css-tricks.com/organic-tabs/) but am having difficulty when changing tab names and adding tabs. Here's what I've changed in the CSS:

```
#example-one li.nav-one a.current, ul.Monday li a:hover { background-color: #0575f4; color: white; }
#example-one li.nav-two a.current, ul.Tuesday li a:hover { background-color: #d30000; color: white; }
#example-one li.nav-three a.current, ul.jquerytuts li a:hover { background-color: #8d01b0; color: white; }
#example-one li.nav-four a.current, ul.thursday li a:hover { background-color: #FE4902; color: white; }
#example-one li.nav-five a.current, ul.friday li a:hover { background-color: #33CC33; color: white; }
#example-one li.nav-six a.current, ul.saturday li a:hover { background-color: #FF19FF; color: white; }
#example-one li.nav-seven a.current, ul.sunday li a:hover { background-color: #FFFF00; color: white; }
```

And here's what I've changed in the HTML:

```
      <div id="example-one">

<ul class="nav">
            <li class="nav-one"><a href="#Monday" class="current">Monday</a></li>
            <li class="nav-one"><a href="#Tuesday">Tuesday</a></li>
            <li class="nav-one"><a href="#Wednesday">Wednesday</a></li>
            <li class="nav-one"><a href="#classics">Thursday</a></li>
            <li class="nav-one"><a href="#jquerytuts">Friday</a></li>
            <li class="nav-one"><a href="#jquerytuts">Saturday</a></li>
            <li class="nav-one last"><a href="#jquerytuts">Sunday</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="list-wrap">

    <ul id="Monday">
        <li><a href="#test">Some Stuff</a></li>
     </ul>

</div> <!-- END List Wrap -->
```

The Java is untouched so same as on the website provided. If I don't change them to "Monday" then it works, but if I change them, like I want to, the hover works, just not changing to a different list.

Any ideas? I'm thinking it might be the Javascript as I don't know how to use Javascript properly...

Comment: Do a search in the code for whatever was there before "Monday", and change it to monday?

Comment: I've tried that, "Featured" has been replaced in everything and still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/r6My9/3/) an example on jsfiddle with your css at the bottom.

i've changing tab name (first) and adding tab (last).

```
<div id="example-one">

        <ul class="nav">
            <li class="nav-one"><a href="#featured" class="current">Rename Featured</a></li> <!-- rename -->
            <li class="nav-two"><a href="#core">Core</a></li>
            <li class="nav-three"><a href="#jquerytuts">jQuery</a></li>
            <li class="nav-four "><a href="#classics">Classics</a></li>
            <li class="nav-five last"><a href="#jquerytuts">Adding tab</a></li><!-- add -->
        </ul>
        [...]
```

That is what you wanted?